# Compare string byte against char c++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char, compare

What I want is to iterate through a string, and for each of the characters in this string, compare it against a certain character, for example "M". `std::string::find` won't work for me as the order in which the characters appear in the string matters (e.g. in roman numerals MC is different to CM).

The code I've got (I'm compiling with c++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
  string str = ("Test Mstring");
  for (auto it = str.begin(); it < str.end(); it++) {
    if (strcmp(*it, "M") == 0) cout << "M!1!!1!" << endl;
  }
}
```

The console error display:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:10:16: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
     if (strcmp(*it, "M") == 0) cout << "M!1!!1!" << endl;
                ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/cstring:42:0,
                 from test.cc:2:
/usr/include/string.h:136:12: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
```

Comment: Not an answer but a potentially helpful link for your metaproblem: [Boost.Spirit example for parsing Roman numerals](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/roman_numerals.html)

Comment: I don't understand why string find will not work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereferencing an iterator obtained from an `std::string` returns a `char`. Your code simply needs to be:

```
if (*it == 'M') cout << "M!1!!1!" << endl;
```

Also:

- Note 'M' != "M". In C++, double quotes define a string literal, which is terminated by a null byte, whereas single quotes define a single char.
- Do not use `endl` unless you intend on flushing the stdout buffer. `\n` is a lot faster.
- `strcmp` in C++ is usually a code smell.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of a string are characters, like `'M'`, not strings.

```
string str = "Test Mstring";
for (auto it = str.begin(); it < str.end(); it++) {
    if (*it == 'M') cout << "M!1!!1!" << endl;
}
```

or

```
string str = "Test Mstring";
for (auto ch: str) {
    if (ch == 'M') cout << "M!1!!1!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` compares entire strings,so if you compare `"mex"` with `"m"`, they are not equal and you can't compare `char` to `char` from `string` in this function, because to compare chars, you can use string as array, e.g.

```
string c = "asd";
string d = "dss";
if(c[0]==d[0] /* ... */
if(c[0]=='a') /*... */
```

Remember that `it` is pointer to char in string, so when dereference, you have to compare to char

```
if(*it=='c')
```

By the way, why do you mix C and C++ strings? You use `string` as in C++ but function `strcmp` comes from C library

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char &c){ if(c == 'M') cout<< "M!1!!1!"<<endl; });
```

Iterator is pointing to a char within the string variable and you don't have to do a string compare